# Why Flexbox does not shrink to its content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using a flexbox and trying to shrink it to fit the size of the navigation bar. Without using the flexbox, the size of the navigation bar became too huge, so I thought it would be convenient to use flexbox. But because of the extra space of the first flexbox (navigation bar), my second flexbox (where I was going to put images and text) gets located very far to the right side...
For example, I tried using flex-basis: auto, to shrink the size of the box. However, no matter what I do, the flexbox stays the same size:

[image]

And below is my code:

```css
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 500%;
}

.one {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
}

.two {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}


.sidebar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Links on mouse-over */
.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #dd1d5e;
}
```

```html
 <section>
        <div class="flexContainer">
            <div class="one">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <a href="#">Holiday</a>
                    <a href="#">Vegetarian</a>
                    <a href="#">Dessert</a>
                    <a href="#">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="two">
                this is second box.
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Any advice will be appreciated...

Comment: `flex:1 1 auto` is equal to `flex-grow:1` <-- expands as much as possible , `flex-shrink:1` <-- can shrink , `flex-basis:auto` <-- no width specified here . Also, `justify-content` , `margin` or no flex property would do ... what is `width:500%` purpose *(it shrinks because of `flex:1` **1** `auto`)*?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inpu. I'd like to keep the flexbox since it's easier for me control (?), so when I adjust ```flex:1 1 auto``` to just ```flex: 1``` or ```flex-shrink: 1```, it really doesn't change anything. Also, using ```flex-shrink:1, flex-basis:auto``` does not change....

Comment: ... what is `width:500%` purpose *(it shrinks because of `flex:1` **1** `auto`)*? ;)

Comment: make it simple: css of snippet update : `.flexContainer {
    display: flex;  
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    overflow: auto;/* is there a max-height */
}

.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #dd1d5e;
}`

Comment: Actually, I just did inspect again, and it did work!! The size got reduced! Thank you!! Can you tell me what exactly was the issues? I'm still a bit confused..

Comment: width:500% + flex : 1 1 auto i guess ;)